# Extract all keys in nested json data with arbitray depth

Tags: python, json

I have a json which is little more than an unordered dump, which consits of a mix of dicts, lists and unicode values nested at depth ranging from 1 to 10. Here is a rough simplified example of what I'm dealing with:

```
{'name': 'TheDude',
 'age': '19',
 'hobbies': {
         'love': 'eating',
         'hate': 'reading',
         'like': [
                 {'outdoor': {
                         'teamsport': 'soccer',
                        }
                 }
                 ]
        }
  }
```

I want the following output (based on the above):

```
[name, age, hobbies_love, hobbies_hate, hobbies_like_outdoor_teamsport]
```

I tried the following code:

```
def printinoice(dictionary,arr):
    for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
        arr.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in printinoice(v,arr):
                arr.append(result)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                for result in printinoice(d,arr):
                    arr.append(result)
    return arr
```

based on [this](https://gist.github.com/douglasmiranda/5127251) but no luck so far. Anyone have a good idea on how to make it work?

Comment: `... [key7: {key8: 'eight,}] ...` is not a valid Python data structure. Also, pls make the keys real string literals, so willing helpers can copy and paste your sample input.

Comment: Amended the question for clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following recursive function will work:

```
def deep_keys(dct):
   if not isinstance(dct, (dict, list)):
      return ['']
   if isinstance(dct, list):
      return [dk for x in dct for dk in deep_keys(x)]
   return [k+('_'+dk if dk else '') for k, v in dct.items() for dk in deep_keys(v)]

>>> deep_keys(d)
['name', 'age', 'hobbies_love', 'hobbies_hate', 'hobbies_like_outdoor_teamsport']
```

It is easiest to not to assume a given type for the function argument, so that you can just pass any nested stuff (i.e. `list` elements and `dict` values) down the recursion.

Comment: can you explain this part: return [dk for x in dct for dk in deep_keys(x)]